# Embedding Layer in Python: How to Use Correctly with Torchsummary?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

This is a minimally working/reproducible example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torchsummary import summary

class Network(nn.Module): 
    def __init__(self, channels_img, features_d, num_classes, img_size): 
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.disc = nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels = channels_img + 1, 
            out_channels = features_d, 
            kernel_size = (4,4)
        )

        # ConditionalGan: 
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(
            num_embeddings = num_classes, 
            embedding_dim = img_size * img_size
        )

   def forward(self, x, labels): 
        embedding = self.embed(labels).view(labels.shape[0], 1, self.img_size, self.img_size)
        x = torch.cat([x, embedding], dim = 1)
        return self.disc(x) 
    
# device: 
device = torch.device("cpu")

# hyperparameter: 
batch_size = 64

# Initialize model: 
model = Network(
    channels_img = 1, 
    features_d = 16, 
    num_classes = 10, 
    img_size = 28).to(device) 

# Print model summary: 
summary(
    model, 
    input_size = [(1, 28, 28), (1, 28, 28)], # MNIST
    batch_size = batch_size
)
```

The error message I get is (for the line with `summary(...)`):

`Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have scalar type Long; but got torch.cuda.FloatTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)`

I saw in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56360644/pytorch-runtimeerror-expected-tensor-for-argument-1-indices-to-have-scalar-t), that `.to(torch.int64)` is supposed to help, but I honestly don't know where to write it.

Thank you!

Comment: I think the problem is about `labels`, so cast it to `long` here: `self.embed(labels.long())...`. This should clear this particular error.

Comment: Please feel free to make this an answer, and I will mark it as accepted as soon as I see it! It turns out, you pointed exactly to the right point, I had experimented with `x.to(torch.int64)` at the right place.. What works for me now is `self.embed(labels.to(torch.int64))`. :)

Comment: *If* you might also provide an answer on WHY one has to write `self.embed(labels.to(torch.int64))` instead of `self.embed(labels)`, I would really appreciate that.

Comment: Tried to give an answer, good luck with your work!

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
self.embed(labels)...
```

An embedding layer is kind of a mapping between discrete indices and continuous values, as stated [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Embedding.html). That is, its inputs should be integers and it will give you back floats. In your case, for example, you are *embedding* class labels of the MNIST which range from 0 to 9, to a contiuum (for some reason that I don't know as i'm not familiar with GANs :)). But in short, that embedding layer will give a transformation of `10 -> 784` for you and those 10 numbers should be integers, PyTorch says.

A fancy name for an integer type is "long", so you need to make sure the data type of what goes into `self.embed` is of that type. There are some ways to do that:

```
self.embed(labels.long())
```

or

```
self.embed(labels.to(torch.long))
```

or

```
self.embed(labels.to(torch.int64))
```

Long datatype is really an 64 bit integer (you may see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html)), so all these work.