# How can torch.cat only have one tensor?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I think there is an error in line 53 of the following code:

[CycleGan, Buffer for Images](https://github.com/junyanz/pytorch-CycleGAN-and-pix2pix/blob/master/util/image_pool.py/)

It says:

```
return_images = torch.cat(return_images, 0)  # collect all the images and return
```

What do you think, what should it read correctly? After having gone throught the code, I am unfortunately not sure what this specific line is supposed to do, but I think I understand the rest until line 52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`torch.cat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html)'s first argument is expected to be a *sequence of tensors* rather than a single tensor. So you pass in like:

```
torch.cat([tensor_1, tensor_2, tensor_3])       # the right way
```

instead of

```
torch.cat(tensor_1, tensor_2, tensor_3)         # not the right way
```

In the code you linked, they are forming a list called `return_images` which contains many tensors in it.

[`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) has the same behaviour too and PyTorch designers probably mimicked the choice from there. ("cat" is short for "concatenate" which is hard to write!).

Comment: May I ask: Do you think you could also help me with this [PyTorch-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66831061/embedding-layer-in-python-how-to-use-correctly-with-torchsummary)?

Comment: @HulioAlmedo Glad to be of help! I left a comment there that *i think* solves that problem. (but i'm not familiar with GANs and not good at embeddings, so any error after that, I might not be able to answer :))